# Setting css with jquery losing setting after page refresh

Tags: css

I'm doing a simple setting of a css property when an element is clicked.
Then I do a page refresh, and the css setting is gone.
How do I make the css setting stick?

Comment: You need to store the change somewhere, like in a cookie, local storage, or a database.

Comment: Store the value of the setting in a cookie named setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cookie for this

```
   $(function(){
       var cookieval = $.cookie('cookie-key');
       if (cookieval === 'something'){
          //here restore style 
       } 
    });
```